# encryption of message "DATACONFANTIALITY" with key playfair using playfair cipher

Tags: playfair

actually i have solved the above mentioned problem but i want to check weather it is correct or not. my question is that how to encrypt the message DATACONFANTIALITY using the playfair cipher where the key is playfair

Comment: DATACONFANTIALITY or DATACONF**IDE**NTIALITY?

Answer (score 2):

The square used is

`P L A Y F
I R B C D
E G H K M
N O Q S T
U V W X Z`

Dataconfidentiality becomes bf qf rs tp ri nu nd ya dn cy (assuming we pad with x)

Done using [this simulation](http://rumkin.com/tools/cipher/playfair.php)